# Backbone JS - Combination of collection, views and models

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I had the following setup now in three different projects, so I thought maybe it's worth asking here. There's a chance I'm not the only person wondering about this.

So there it comes:

- I have a list of objects
- The list items have a special function like draggable or onClick-Events

---

My question: How do I build this scenario with Backbone?

I guess I create a model and a view for my list objects. I use a collection for keeping together my objects.

Now I wonder: Do I instantiate the object view in the model constructor and instantiate the models in the collection constructor? Or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither; use a mediator to instantiate the views and inject them with their model/collection.

Marionette.js has [a nice implementation for this sort of mediating object, called `Controller`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.controller.html) - I suggest you check it out.

Further more, you don't have to explicitly instantiate the collection models - just declare their type in the collection's prototype, e.g.:

```js
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // do some shit
});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel // pass the type for the collection to instantiate
});
```

Taking our mediator/controller approach further, this is how it could be done (with Marionette.js):

```js
var MyController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.myCollection = new MyCollection();
        this.myCollectionView = new MyCollectionView({
            collection: this.myCollection
        });
    }
});
```

This, of course, is just a skeleton code, meant to roughly demonstrate the MVC approach, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: Hm, MVC is of course a nice idea. But how would I do it if I'd like to stick to Backbone? My application is not so complex that I need a full JS framework, roughly a skeleton to make my code more readable and maintainable...

Comment: well, MVC should not stay in the "nice idea" realm - it should guide you through the app design and architecture. i suggest you embrace it for those reasons.

Comment: and about "how would you do it if you'd like to stick to backbone" - there's no contradiction here - just do it as i suggested in the answer (also, if the answer is of value to you, please upvote it, or tick it accepted if it solved your issue).

Comment: thx for your effort. it's not 100% what I want but I went a little different way now. So I think i fits as a solid answer :)